# MySQL select rows where numeric portions of varchar match numbers

Tags: mysql, regex, numeric, varchar

I am trying to have a row of data containing 'tn450' to result when searching by '450.'

I've been researching on here but can't seem to combine the REGEXP and LIKE commands

```
    SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE products_comomon_name REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]{10}$' LIKE ('450')
```

Comment: Why do you need a regex at all? Why not just use "LIKE '%450'" or something similar?

Comment: You need an `AND` or `OR` to combine two different conditions: `WHERE col REGEXP <something> AND col LIKE '%450%'`

Comment: `'^[[:digit:]]{10}$'` will only match if the column contains **exactly** 10 digits, with nothing else around it. Why would you use that regexp if you want to allow `tn` before the number?